# How to select element from the list, click on it, go back to the list and select next element using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm trying to write a small app (robot), which will be using a webdriver to log in to the site, search for some data in a search field and then select each element from the list, by clicking one of them, going back to the list and then selecting next element with the same class name but different parent.
I think I know how to get all elements with the same class name:

```
List<WebElement> incognito_user = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='results']/li[2]/div/h3/a"))
```

but I need some help with for loops that will index all of them and also go to next page.

Comment: Could you post code for your best attempt? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually I want to see your page.(maybe .jsp). But I think  you need to make your list has unique ids and find using this id with for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue a bit different way:

```
    boolean inLoop = true;
    int maxPages = 2;

    while(inLoop && (maxPages-- > 0)) {
        List<WebElement> incognito_user = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
        String openInNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
        for (WebElement element : incognito_user) {
            element.sendKeys(openInNewTab);
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
            waitSecs(randomNumber(5, 10));
            driver.switchTo().window(new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()).get(1));
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()).get(0));
            waitSecs(randomNumber(5,10));
        }

        List<WebElement> nextElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
        if (nextElements.size() > 0) {
            nextElements.get(0).click();
            waitSecs(randomNumber(5,10));
        }
        else {
            inLoop = false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your efort.
Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

If u need to deal with list of elements, have just created a wrapper for selenium

> click()

```
public String clickButton(String parentClassIdentifier,String childClassIdentifier ,String index) throws IOException{

                WebElement parentButtonList = (WebElement)driver.findElementByXPath((parentClassIdentifier));
                List<WebElement> childButtonList = parentButtonList.findElementsByXPath((childClassIdentifier));
                int button_index = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(index));   // conversion from String to Int
                childButtonList.get(button_index).click();
                Application_Log.info("Clicked on button :- " ,childClassIdentifier    +index );
                return "pass";

}
```

Simply use clickButton() by passing the identifiers and the list index in the code

Comment: Wow, that is terrible code. Forcing lookup by two xpath expressions, but naming the xpath parameters "...Identifier". A useless cast to `WebElement`. Some undocumented property magic. Always returning the same string instead of making the method `void`. Declaring to throw `IOException` for no reason. An undeclared logging member.